# How do i tell ubuntu to only install is asked for and do not bring other dependencies which will break the whole system?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, package-management, python, python-2.7

How can i only install `python-webkit` but not other packages? which is showing to install? (no gstreamer*.*, i do not want to have any single files installed in my distro because of GPL license and it slows my machine a lot)

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 python-webkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0
Suggested packages:
  gstreamer-codec-install gnome-codec-install gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 333 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,231 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install pkg1 pkg2 ....`

To disable installing recommends by default, please see:
[How can I set up aptitude-curses so that it doesn't automatically select *recommended* packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138297/how-can-i-set-up-aptitude-curses-so-that-it-doesnt-automatically-select-recomm/138313#138313)
(applies to apt-get too)